# 'str' object has no attribute 'exists'/ 'is_file'

Tags: python

I am taking inputs from the user and at run time, I will check if there is a script exists in the current directory with the name passed by the user. If the file exists I will consider it as valid otherwise invalid.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Main script')
parser.add_argument('--script', nargs='+',type=str)

script_list = process_args.script 

  for item in script_list:
      scn_script = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),item+'.py')
      if scn_script.exists():
         print(scn_script)
      else:
         print("Not exists")
```

In my current directory I am having
abc.py, sample.py,  test.py, names.py

If the user passes  entry,sample,hello, names through command line
It should print sample.py exists
names.py exists

> > ERROR 'str' object has no attribute 'exists'

It's clear that type str has no attribute "exists"

> > > dir(str)
> > > ['**add**', '**class**', '**contains**', '**delattr**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**getitem**', '**getnewargs**', '**getslice**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**le**', '**len**', '**lt**', '**mod**', '**mul**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**rmod**', '**rmul**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']

Any Idea how can I get this issue fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`if os.path.exists(scn_script):`

Comment: @Vulwsztyn Please do not fish for reputation by requesting that the OP upvote/accept your answer. It is unnecessary, as OP will naturally upvote/accept if it does, indeed, work for them.